# Excluding .svn directories with WinRar

Tags: svn, powershell, winrar

I have a PowerShell script I use for creating distributions that copies compiled files from a few places and zips them up with winrar. In the script, I change to a directory containing the folders I want to run and execute this:

```
Invoke-Expression ($WinRAR + " a " + $zipPath + " " + $WinRARFilter + " " + $DistName + "-zip " + $WinRAROpts)
```

Which actually executes this:

```
E:\Progs\WinRar\WinRar.exe a C:\Users\Echilon\Documents\Coding\ResourceBlender-Express\trunk\dist\resourceblender-express_1.44-zip.zip -x*\.svn\* -x*\.svn -x\.svn resourceblender-express-zip -r -s -m5 -inul
```

Yet none of the .svn directories are excluded from the zip file. This used to work and I have no idea why it doesn't now, but I can't get it to exclude the right files.

The full script is on codeplex at [http://resourceblender.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/27742?projectName=resourceblender#456701](http://resourceblender.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/27742?projectName=resourceblender#45670) (at the bottom of the script)

Could someone with some experience in PowerShell shed some light on this please?

Comment: This is more of a winrar command line issue, not powershell.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, solved using:

```
-x*.svn\
```

I use WinRar v3.93 for Windows. Please note the final backslash.

Answer (score 11):

The right way of doing this is to perform a **svn export** which will create a copy of the project without the .svn directories (and anything else not version controlled) and then do the zip.

Comment: I know, but I'd rather not write additonal scripts right now to export a copy. The alternative is just Remomve-Item -Recurse which I want to avoid if possible.

Comment: that is a very nice answer to a different question

Answer (score 2):

This is a PowerShell issue. I put the same command in the Command Prompt and BOOM!

```
winrar a -ehs -x*\.svn\* -u -r -afrar -m3 "dest file.rar" "source folder"
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Neil Butterworth comment regarding the use of the `svn export` command being more appropriate in this case.
Talking about `WinRar` you might consider using an [`-e`](http://acritum.com/winrar/manual/html_helpsweattr.htm) switch to skip hidden folders (.svn is a hidden folder) and an [`-ep`](http://acritum.com/winrar/manual/html_helpswep.htm) switch to exclude it by name.

Please refer to [WinRar manual](http://acritum.com/winrar/manual/index.html) for more information

Comment: I know this should work, but adding -eh to the switches has no effect. This is really starting to baffle me, the .svn folders are definitely hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found this page with no solution, so for other people googling it  the correct switch is :

```
-x*\.svn\*
```

Comment: That was actually one of the combinations which didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using

```
-x*\.svn*
```

This will ignore the actual .svn folder and not just everything inside of it. I'm also using WinRAR 3.80. Have you tried updating your version of winrar ?

Thought the svn export method worked out a lot better for me cuz I didn't get all the debug builds and misc .dlls